# Incorrect syntax near 'File'

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying to create a simple table called FileTypes.

I tried the following:

```
 create table TestDB.dbo.FileTypes(    
 Date datetime not null, 
 File varchar(100) not null,
 Type varchar(20) not null )
```

But I get a error stating :

```
 Incorrect Syntax near 'File' & 
 Incorrect Syntax near varchar(100) and varchar(20).Expecting SELECT, or '('
```

what is this about ?? kindly help.. thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try enclosing `Date`, `File` and `Type` in square brackets - they are reserved words in SQL.

```
create table TestDB.dbo.FileTypes(    
    [Date] datetime not null, 
    [File] varchar(100) not null,
    [Type] varchar(20) not null )
```